# Criar marcação com símbolos pré-definidos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Não sabia como escolher um título específico diante de minha dúvida, então foi esse meio vago mesmo.

Estou a um certo tempo tentando fazer o seguinte:

Supondo que eu tenha o `<p>`:

```
  <p>Olá, $está tudo$ bem?</p>
```

Eu preciso de um *script* que faça com que o que esteja entre os símbolos "$" receba uma formatação específica. Por exemplo, mude de cor, ou seja sublinhado.

Contudo, preciso que isso seja possíveis, com mais de uma formatação para mais de um tipo de símbolo. Por exemplo:

```
  <p>Olá, $ #está# tudo$ bem?</p>
```

Nesse caso, que o que esteja entre "$" seja, por exemplo sublinhado, e entre "#" seja, por exemplo, verde.

**O meu problema**

Estou colocando frações em meu site como esta:

[image: fórmula]

Fiz a fração com esse código:

```css
.fraction_style {
 height: auto; width: auto; line-height: 27px; 
}
.fraction_style .fraction{
 width: auto; display: inline-block; text-align: center;  line-height: 27px; 
 
}
.fraction_style .fraction .fraction_top{
 text-align: center; display: block;
 vertical-align: center;
}

.fraction_style .fraction .fraction_bottom{
 width: 100%; text-align: center; border-top: 2px solid; display: block; margin-top: -30px; 
}

.fraction_style .equal_fraction {
 width: auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: 70%;
}
```

```html
<span class='fraction_style'> 
  <span class='fraction' > 
    <span class='fraction_top' > &pi; x r³ x 4 </span>
    <br> 
    <span class='fraction_bottom'>3</span>
  </span> 
  <span class='equal_fraction'> = Ve </span>
</span>
```

Contudo, escrever todas essas `span` demandaria muito tempo, já que os valores dessas frações são manipulados por javascript.

Então o que eu desejava era que com símbolos pré-definidos, um script os substituiria pelas `span. Por exemplo:

**$ # @** π x r³ x 4 **@** / **%** 3 **% # &** = x **& $**

Onde:

$ -> Tag: `<span class='fraction_style'>`

*#* -> Tag: `<span class='fraction'>`

@ -> Tag: `<span class='fraction_top'>`

% -> Tag: `<span class='fraction_bottom'>`

& -> Tag: `<span class='equal_fraction'>`

Sei que é bastante complexo e bagunçado, mas não tinha a menor ideia de como fazer isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>Estou postando como resposta separada pelo fato de o JS da outra ter chegado no limite de caracteres do SOpt</sub>

### Para matemática:

Dois projetos interessantes são o [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) e o [AsciiMathMl](http://asciimath.org/), incorporado no primeiro e que nos interessa pela simplicidade da sintaxe.

Veja um exemplo em ação:

```html
<h3>Original:</h3>
sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2
<h3>Resultado:</h3>
`sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Com o interpretador [AsciiMathMl](http://asciimath.org/) do [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), basta escrever a fórmula entre *backticks*, que o JS dá conta de fazer a conversão.

Alternativamente, o HTML 5 prevê o MathML, mas como de costume, sua implementação depende de *browsers* atualizados. Neste caso, o [AsciiMathMl](http://asciimath.org/) serve como um "simplificador", pois já gera o MathML diretamente de uma string simples, como no exemplo acima (o que muda no exemplo é que usamos o MathJax para exibição, e não MathMl).

Answer (score 7):

Como você não especificou muitos detalhes na pergunta, segue uma resposta "genérica":

Sim, é possível e já há várias coisas prontas neste sentido. Por exemplo, o [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/) faz em JS algo similar ao que o SOpt faz, com *markdown*.

Veja um demo funcional:

```js
/* Este é o código obtido em http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js e minificado */
(function(){function e(e){this.tokens=[],this.tokens.links={},this.options=e||l.defaults,this.rules=o.normal,this.options.gfm&&(this.options.tables?this.rules=o.tables:this.rules=o.gfm)}function t(e,t){if(this.options=t||l.defaults,this.links=e,this.rules=h.normal,!this.links)throw new Error("Tokens array requires a `links` property.");this.options.gfm?this.options.breaks?this.rules=h.breaks:this.rules=h.gfm:this.options.pedantic&&(this.rules=h.pedantic)}function n(e){this.tokens=[],this.token=null,this.options=e||l.defaults}function s(e,t){return e.replace(t?/&/g:/&(?!#?\w+;)/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/"/g,"&quot;").replace(/'/g,"&#39;")}function r(e,t){return e=e.source,t=t||"",function n(s,r){return s?(r=r.source||r,r=r.replace(/(^|[^\[])\^/g,"$1"),e=e.replace(s,r),n):new RegExp(e,t)}}function i(){}function a(e){for(var t,n,s=1;s<arguments.length;s++){t=arguments[s];for(n in t)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,n)&&(e[n]=t[n])}return e}function l(t,s){try{return s&&(s=a({},l.defaults,s)),n.parse(e.lex(t,s),s)}catch(r){if(r.message+="\nPlease report this to https://github.com/chjj/marked.",(s||l.defaults).silent)return"An error occured:\n"+r.message;throw r}}var o={newline:/^\n+/,code:/^( {4}[^\n]+\n*)+/,fences:i,hr:/^( *[-*_]){3,} *(?:\n+|$)/,heading:/^ *(#{1,6}) *([^\n]+?) *#* *(?:\n+|$)/,nptable:i,lheading:/^([^\n]+)\n *(=|-){3,} *\n*/,blockquote:/^( *>[^\n]+(\n[^\n]+)*\n*)+/,list:/^( *)(bull) [\s\S]+?(?:hr|\n{2,}(?! )(?!\1bull )\n*|\s*$)/,html:/^ *(?:comment|closed|closing) *(?:\n{2,}|\s*$)/,def:/^ *\[([^\]]+)\]: *<?([^\s>]+)>?(?: +["(]([^\n]+)[")])? *(?:\n+|$)/,table:i,paragraph:/^((?:[^\n]+\n?(?!hr|heading|lheading|blockquote|tag|def))+)\n*/,text:/^[^\n]+/};o.bullet=/(?:[*+-]|\d+\.)/,o.item=/^( *)(bull) [^\n]*(?:\n(?!\1bull )[^\n]*)*/,o.item=r(o.item,"gm")(/bull/g,o.bullet)(),o.list=r(o.list)(/bull/g,o.bullet)("hr",/\n+(?=(?: *[-*_]){3,} *(?:\n+|$))/)(),o._tag="(?!(?:a|em|strong|small|s|cite|q|dfn|abbr|data|time|code|var|samp|kbd|sub|sup|i|b|u|mark|ruby|rt|rp|bdi|bdo|span|br|wbr|ins|del|img)\\b)\\w+(?!:/|@)\\b",o.html=r(o.html)("comment",/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/)("closed",/<(tag)[\s\S]+?<\/\1>/)("closing",/<tag(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*?>/)(/tag/g,o._tag)(),o.paragraph=r(o.paragraph)("hr",o.hr)("heading",o.heading)("lheading",o.lheading)("blockquote",o.blockquote)("tag","<"+o._tag)("def",o.def)(),o.normal=a({},o),o.gfm=a({},o.normal,{fences:/^ *(`{3,}|~{3,}) *(\w+)? *\n([\s\S]+?)\s*\1 *(?:\n+|$)/,paragraph:/^/}),o.gfm.paragraph=r(o.paragraph)("(?!","(?!"+o.gfm.fences.source.replace("\\1","\\2")+"|")(),o.tables=a({},o.gfm,{nptable:/^ *(\S.*\|.*)\n *([-:]+ *\|[-| :]*)\n((?:.*\|.*(?:\n|$))*)\n*/,table:/^ *\|(.+)\n *\|( *[-:]+[-| :]*)\n((?: *\|.*(?:\n|$))*)\n*/}),e.rules=o,e.lex=function(t,n){var s=new e(n);return s.lex(t)},e.prototype.lex=function(e){return e=e.replace(/\r\n|\r/g,"\n").replace(/\t/g,"    ").replace(/\u00a0/g," ").replace(/\u2424/g,"\n"),this.token(e,!0)},e.prototype.token=function(e,t){for(var n,s,r,i,a,l,h,u,c,e=e.replace(/^ +$/gm,"");e;)if((r=this.rules.newline.exec(e))&&(e=e.substring(r[0].length),r[0].length>1&&this.tokens.push({type:"space"})),r=this.rules.code.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),r=r[0].replace(/^ {4}/gm,""),this.tokens.push({type:"code",text:this.options.pedantic?r:r.replace(/\n+$/,"")});else if(r=this.rules.fences.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"code",lang:r[2],text:r[3]});else if(r=this.rules.heading.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"heading",depth:r[1].length,text:r[2]});else if(t&&(r=this.rules.nptable.exec(e))){for(e=e.substring(r[0].length),l={type:"table",header:r[1].replace(/^ *| *\| *$/g,"").split(/ *\| */),align:r[2].replace(/^ *|\| *$/g,"").split(/ *\| */),cells:r[3].replace(/\n$/,"").split("\n")},u=0;u<l.align.length;u++)/^ *-+: *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="right":/^ *:-+: *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="center":/^ *:-+ *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="left":l.align[u]=null;for(u=0;u<l.cells.length;u++)l.cells[u]=l.cells[u].split(/ *\| */);this.tokens.push(l)}else if(r=this.rules.lheading.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"heading",depth:"="===r[2]?1:2,text:r[1]});else if(r=this.rules.hr.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"hr"});else if(r=this.rules.blockquote.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"blockquote_start"}),r=r[0].replace(/^ *> ?/gm,""),this.token(r,t),this.tokens.push({type:"blockquote_end"});else if(r=this.rules.list.exec(e)){for(e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"list_start",ordered:isFinite(r[2])}),r=r[0].match(this.rules.item),this.options.smartLists&&(i=o.bullet.exec(r[0])[0]),n=!1,c=r.length,u=0;c>u;u++)l=r[u],h=l.length,l=l.replace(/^ *([*+-]|\d+\.) +/,""),~l.indexOf("\n ")&&(h-=l.length,l=this.options.pedantic?l.replace(/^ {1,4}/gm,""):l.replace(new RegExp("^ {1,"+h+"}","gm"),"")),this.options.smartLists&&u!==c-1&&(a=o.bullet.exec(r[u+1])[0],i===a||"."===i[1]&&"."===a[1]||(e=r.slice(u+1).join("\n")+e,u=c-1)),s=n||/\n\n(?!\s*$)/.test(l),u!==c-1&&(n="\n"===l[l.length-1],s||(s=n)),this.tokens.push({type:s?"loose_item_start":"list_item_start"}),this.token(l,!1),this.tokens.push({type:"list_item_end"});this.tokens.push({type:"list_end"})}else if(r=this.rules.html.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:this.options.sanitize?"paragraph":"html",pre:"pre"===r[1],text:r[0]});else if(t&&(r=this.rules.def.exec(e)))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.links[r[1].toLowerCase()]={href:r[2],title:r[3]};else if(t&&(r=this.rules.table.exec(e))){for(e=e.substring(r[0].length),l={type:"table",header:r[1].replace(/^ *| *\| *$/g,"").split(/ *\| */),align:r[2].replace(/^ *|\| *$/g,"").split(/ *\| */),cells:r[3].replace(/(?: *\| *)?\n$/,"").split("\n")},u=0;u<l.align.length;u++)/^ *-+: *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="right":/^ *:-+: *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="center":/^ *:-+ *$/.test(l.align[u])?l.align[u]="left":l.align[u]=null;for(u=0;u<l.cells.length;u++)l.cells[u]=l.cells[u].replace(/^ *\| *| *\| *$/g,"").split(/ *\| */);this.tokens.push(l)}else if(t&&(r=this.rules.paragraph.exec(e)))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"paragraph",text:"\n"===r[1][r[1].length-1]?r[1].slice(0,-1):r[1]});else if(r=this.rules.text.exec(e))e=e.substring(r[0].length),this.tokens.push({type:"text",text:r[0]});else if(e)throw new Error("Infinite loop on byte: "+e.charCodeAt(0));return this.tokens};var h={escape:/^\\([\\`*{}\[\]()#+\-.!_>])/,autolink:/^<([^ >]+(@|:\/)[^ >]+)>/,url:i,tag:/^<!--[\s\S]*?-->|^<\/?\w+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*?>/,link:/^!?\[(inside)\]\(href\)/,reflink:/^!?\[(inside)\]\s*\[([^\]]*)\]/,nolink:/^!?\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*)\]/,strong:/^__([\s\S]+?)__(?!_)|^\*\*([\s\S]+?)\*\*(?!\*)/,em:/^\b_((?:__|[\s\S])+?)_\b|^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)\*(?!\*)/,code:/^(`+)\s*([\s\S]*?[^`])\s*\1(?!`)/,br:/^ {2,}\n(?!\s*$)/,del:i,text:/^[\s\S]+?(?=[\\<!\[_*`]| {2,}\n|$)/};h._inside=/(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\]]|\](?=[^\[]*\]))*/,h._href=/\s*<?([^\s]*?)>?(?:\s+['"]([\s\S]*?)['"])?\s*/,h.link=r(h.link)("inside",h._inside)("href",h._href)(),h.reflink=r(h.reflink)("inside",h._inside)(),h.normal=a({},h),h.pedantic=a({},h.normal,{strong:/^__(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)__(?!_)|^\*\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*\*(?!\*)/,em:/^_(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)_(?!_)|^\*(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)\*(?!\*)/}),h.gfm=a({},h.normal,{escape:r(h.escape)("])","~|])")(),url:/^(https?:\/\/[^\s<]+[^<.,:;"')\]\s])/,del:/^~~(?=\S)([\s\S]*?\S)~~/,text:r(h.text)("]|","~]|")("|","|https?://|")()}),h.breaks=a({},h.gfm,{br:r(h.br)("{2,}","*")(),text:r(h.gfm.text)("{2,}","*")()}),t.rules=h,t.output=function(e,n,s){var r=new t(n,s);return r.output(e)},t.prototype.output=function(e){for(var t,n,r,i,a="";e;)if(i=this.rules.escape.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+=i[1];else if(i=this.rules.autolink.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),"@"===i[2]?(n=":"===i[1][6]?this.mangle(i[1].substring(7)):this.mangle(i[1]),r=this.mangle("mailto:")+n):(n=s(i[1]),r=n),a+='<a href="'+r+'">'+n+"</a>";else if(i=this.rules.url.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),n=s(i[1]),r=n,a+='<a href="'+r+'">'+n+"</a>";else if(i=this.rules.tag.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+=this.options.sanitize?s(i[0]):i[0];else if(i=this.rules.link.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+=this.outputLink(i,{href:i[2],title:i[3]});else if((i=this.rules.reflink.exec(e))||(i=this.rules.nolink.exec(e))){if(e=e.substring(i[0].length),t=(i[2]||i[1]).replace(/\s+/g," "),t=this.links[t.toLowerCase()],!t||!t.href){a+=i[0][0],e=i[0].substring(1)+e;continue}a+=this.outputLink(i,t)}else if(i=this.rules.strong.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+="<strong>"+this.output(i[2]||i[1])+"</strong>";else if(i=this.rules.em.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+="<em>"+this.output(i[2]||i[1])+"</em>";else if(i=this.rules.code.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+="<code>"+s(i[2],!0)+"</code>";else if(i=this.rules.br.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+="<br>";else if(i=this.rules.del.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+="<del>"+this.output(i[1])+"</del>";else if(i=this.rules.text.exec(e))e=e.substring(i[0].length),a+=s(i[0]);else if(e)throw new Error("Infinite loop on byte: "+e.charCodeAt(0));return a},t.prototype.outputLink=function(e,t){return"!"!==e[0][0]?'<a href="'+s(t.href)+'"'+(t.title?' title="'+s(t.title)+'"':"")+">"+this.output(e[1])+"</a>":'<img src="'+s(t.href)+'" alt="'+s(e[1])+'"'+(t.title?' title="'+s(t.title)+'"':"")+">"},t.prototype.mangle=function(e){for(var t,n="",s=e.length,r=0;s>r;r++)t=e.charCodeAt(r),Math.random()>.5&&(t="x"+t.toString(16)),n+="&#"+t+";";return n},n.parse=function(e,t){var s=new n(t);return s.parse(e)},n.prototype.parse=function(e){this.inline=new t(e.links,this.options),this.tokens=e.reverse();for(var n="";this.next();)n+=this.tok();return n},n.prototype.next=function(){return this.token=this.tokens.pop()},n.prototype.peek=function(){return this.tokens[this.tokens.length-1]||0},n.prototype.parseText=function(){for(var e=this.token.text;"text"===this.peek().type;)e+="\n"+this.next().text;return this.inline.output(e)},n.prototype.tok=function(){switch(this.token.type){case"space":return"";case"hr":return"<hr>\n";case"heading":return"<h"+this.token.depth+">"+this.inline.output(this.token.text)+"</h"+this.token.depth+">\n";case"code":if(this.options.highlight){var e=this.options.highlight(this.token.text,this.token.lang);null!=e&&e!==this.token.text&&(this.token.escaped=!0,this.token.text=e)}return this.token.escaped||(this.token.text=s(this.token.text,!0)),"<pre><code"+(this.token.lang?' class="'+this.options.langPrefix+this.token.lang+'"':"")+">"+this.token.text+"</code></pre>\n";case"table":var t,n,r,i,a,l="";for(l+="<thead>\n<tr>\n",n=0;n<this.token.header.length;n++)t=this.inline.output(this.token.header[n]),l+=this.token.align[n]?'<th align="'+this.token.align[n]+'">'+t+"</th>\n":"<th>"+t+"</th>\n";for(l+="</tr>\n</thead>\n",l+="<tbody>\n",n=0;n<this.token.cells.length;n++){for(r=this.token.cells[n],l+="<tr>\n",a=0;a<r.length;a++)i=this.inline.output(r[a]),l+=this.token.align[a]?'<td align="'+this.token.align[a]+'">'+i+"</td>\n":"<td>"+i+"</td>\n";l+="</tr>\n"}return l+="</tbody>\n","<table>\n"+l+"</table>\n";case"blockquote_start":for(var l="";"blockquote_end"!==this.next().type;)l+=this.tok();return"<blockquote>\n"+l+"</blockquote>\n";case"list_start":for(var o=this.token.ordered?"ol":"ul",l="";"list_end"!==this.next().type;)l+=this.tok();return"<"+o+">\n"+l+"</"+o+">\n";case"list_item_start":for(var l="";"list_item_end"!==this.next().type;)l+="text"===this.token.type?this.parseText():this.tok();return"<li>"+l+"</li>\n";case"loose_item_start":for(var l="";"list_item_end"!==this.next().type;)l+=this.tok();return"<li>"+l+"</li>\n";case"html":return this.token.pre||this.options.pedantic?this.token.text:this.inline.output(this.token.text);case"paragraph":return"<p>"+this.inline.output(this.token.text)+"</p>\n";case"text":return"<p>"+this.parseText()+"</p>\n"}},i.exec=i,l.options=l.setOptions=function(e){return a(l.defaults,e),l},l.defaults={gfm:!0,tables:!0,breaks:!1,pedantic:!1,sanitize:!1,smartLists:!1,silent:!1,highlight:null,langPrefix:"lang-"},l.Parser=n,l.parser=n.parse,l.Lexer=e,l.lexer=e.lex,l.InlineLexer=t,l.inlineLexer=t.output,l.parse=l,"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=l:"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return l}):this.marked=l}).call(function(){return this||("undefined"!=typeof window?window:global)}()),window.PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION=!0;var prettyPrintOne,prettyPrint;!function(){function e(e){function t(e){var t=e.charCodeAt(0);if(92!==t)return t;var n=e.charAt(1);return t=c[n],t?t:n>="0"&&"7">=n?parseInt(e.substring(1),8):"u"===n||"x"===n?parseInt(e.substring(2),16):e.charCodeAt(1)}function n(e){if(32>e)return(16>e?"\\x0":"\\x")+e.toString(16);var t=String.fromCharCode(e);return"\\"===t||"-"===t||"]"===t||"^"===t?"\\"+t:t}function s(e){var s=e.substring(1,e.length-1).match(new RegExp("\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|\\\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\\[0-3][0-7]{0,2}|\\\\[0-7]{1,2}|\\\\[\\s\\S]|-|[^-\\\\]","g")),r=[],i="^"===s[0],a=["["];i&&a.push("^");for(var l=i?1:0,o=s.length;o>l;++l){var h=s[l];if(/\\[bdsw]/i.test(h))a.push(h);else{var u,c=t(h);o>l+2&&"-"===s[l+1]?(u=t(s[l+2]),l+=2):u=c,r.push([c,u]),65>u||c>122||(65>u||c>90||r.push([32|Math.max(65,c),32|Math.min(u,90)]),97>u||c>122||r.push([-33&Math.max(97,c),-33&Math.min(u,122)]))}}r.sort(function(e,t){return e[0]-t[0]||t[1]-e[1]});for(var p=[],g=[],l=0;l<r.length;++l){var d=r[l];d[0]<=g[1]+1?g[1]=Math.max(g[1],d[1]):p.push(g=d)}for(var l=0;l<p.length;++l){var d=p[l];a.push(n(d[0])),d[1]>d[0]&&(d[1]+1>d[0]&&a.push("-"),a.push(n(d[1])))}return a.push("]"),a.join("")}function r(e){for(var t=e.source.match(new RegExp("(?:\\[(?:[^\\x5C\\x5D]|\\\\[\\s\\S])*\\]|\\\\u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}|\\\\x[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|\\\\[0-9]+|\\\\[^ux0-9]|\\(\\?[:!=]|[\\(\\)\\^]|[^\\x5B\\x5C\\(\\)\\^]+)","g")),r=t.length,l=[],o=0,h=0;r>o;++o){var u=t[o];if("("===u)++h;else if("\\"===u.charAt(0)){var c=+u.substring(1);c&&(h>=c?l[c]=-1:t[o]=n(c))}}for(var o=1;o<l.length;++o)-1===l[o]&&(l[o]=++i);for(var o=0,h=0;r>o;++o){var u=t[o];if("("===u)++h,l[h]||(t[o]="(?:");else if("\\"===u.charAt(0)){var c=+u.substring(1);c&&h>=c&&(t[o]="\\"+l[c])}}for(var o=0;r>o;++o)"^"===t[o]&&"^"!==t[o+1]&&(t[o]="");if(e.ignoreCase&&a)for(var o=0;r>o;++o){var u=t[o],p=u.charAt(0);u.length>=2&&"["===p?t[o]=s(u):"\\"!==p&&(t[o]=u.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(e){var t=e.charCodeAt(0);return"["+String.fromCharCode(-33&t,32|t)+"]"}))}return t.join("")}for(var i=0,a=!1,l=!1,o=0,h=e.length;h>o;++o){var u=e[o];if(u.ignoreCase)l=!0;else if(/[a-z]/i.test(u.source.replace(/\\u[0-9a-f]{4}|\\x[0-9a-f]{2}|\\[^ux]/gi,""))){a=!0,l=!1;break}}for(var c={b:8,t:9,n:10,v:11,f:12,r:13},p=[],o=0,h=e.length;h>o;++o){var u=e[o];if(u.global||u.multiline)throw new Error(""+u);p.push("(?:"+r(u)+")")}return new RegExp(p.join("|"),l?"gi":"g")}function t(e,t){function n(e){switch(e.nodeType){case 1:if(s.test(e.className))return;for(var o=e.firstChild;o;o=o.nextSibling)n(o);var h=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();("br"===h||"li"===h)&&(r[l]="\n",a[l<<1]=i++,a[l++<<1|1]=e);break;case 3:case 4:var u=e.nodeValue;u.length&&(u=t?u.replace(/\r\n?/g,"\n"):u.replace(/[ \t\r\n]+/g," "),r[l]=u,a[l<<1]=i,i+=u.length,a[l++<<1|1]=e)}}var s=/(?:^|\s)nocode(?:\s|$)/,r=[],i=0,a=[],l=0;return n(e),{sourceCode:r.join("").replace(/\n$/,""),spans:a}}function n(e,t,n,s){if(t){var r={sourceCode:t,basePos:e};n(r),s.push.apply(s,r.decorations)}}function s(e){for(var t=void 0,n=e.firstChild;n;n=n.nextSibling){var s=n.nodeType;t=1===s?t?e:n:3===s&&U.test(n.nodeValue)?e:t}return t===e?void 0:t}function r(t,s){var r,i={};!function(){for(var n=t.concat(s),a=[],l={},o=0,h=n.length;h>o;++o){var u=n[o],c=u[3];if(c)for(var p=c.length;--p>=0;)i[c.charAt(p)]=u;var g=u[1],d=""+g;l.hasOwnProperty(d)||(a.push(g),l[d]=null)}a.push(/[\0-\uffff]/),r=e(a)}();var a=s.length,l=function(e){for(var t=e.sourceCode,o=e.basePos,u=[o,B],c=0,p=t.match(r)||[],g={},d=0,f=p.length;f>d;++d){var m,b=p[d],x=g[b],y=void 0;if("string"==typeof x)m=!1;else{var v=i[b.charAt(0)];if(v)y=b.match(v[1]),x=v[0];else{for(var k=0;a>k;++k)if(v=s[k],y=b.match(v[1])){x=v[0];break}y||(x=B)}m=x.length>=5&&"lang-"===x.substring(0,5),!m||y&&"string"==typeof y[1]||(m=!1,x=q),m||(g[b]=x)}var w=c;if(c+=b.length,m){var S=y[1],_=b.indexOf(S),C=_+S.length;y[2]&&(C=b.length-y[2].length,_=C-S.length);var N=x.substring(5);n(o+w,b.substring(0,_),l,u),n(o+w+_,S,h(N,S),u),n(o+w+C,b.substring(C),l,u)}else u.push(o+w,x)}e.decorations=u};return l}function i(e){var t=[],n=[];e.tripleQuotedStrings?t.push([E,/^(?:\'\'\'(?:[^\'\\]|\\[\s\S]|\'{1,2}(?=[^\']))*(?:\'\'\'|$)|\"\"\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S]|\"{1,2}(?=[^\"]))*(?:\"\"\"|$)|\'(?:[^\\\']|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$))/,null,"'\""]):e.multiLineStrings?t.push([E,/^(?:\'(?:[^\\\']|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)|\`(?:[^\\\`]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\`|$))/,null,"'\"`"]):t.push([E,/^(?:\'(?:[^\\\'\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\"|$))/,null,"\"'"]),e.verbatimStrings&&n.push([E,/^@\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*(?:\"|$)/,null]);var s=e.hashComments;if(s&&(e.cStyleComments?(s>1?t.push([L,/^#(?:##(?:[^#]|#(?!##))*(?:###|$)|.*)/,null,"#"]):t.push([L,/^#(?:(?:define|e(?:l|nd)if|else|error|ifn?def|include|line|pragma|undef|warning)\b|[^\r\n]*)/,null,"#"]),n.push([E,/^<(?:(?:(?:\.\.\/)*|\/?)(?:[\w-]+(?:\/[\w-]+)+)?[\w-]+\.h(?:h|pp|\+\+)?|[a-z]\w*)>/,null])):t.push([L,/^#[^\r\n]*/,null,"#"])),e.cStyleComments&&(n.push([L,/^\/\/[^\r\n]*/,null]),n.push([L,/^\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)/,null])),e.regexLiterals){var i="/(?=[^/*])(?:[^/\\x5B\\x5C]|\\x5C[\\s\\S]|\\x5B(?:[^\\x5C\\x5D]|\\x5C[\\s\\S])*(?:\\x5D|$))+/";n.push(["lang-regex",new RegExp("^"+D+"("+i+")")])}var a=e.types;a&&n.push([P,a]);var l=(""+e.keywords).replace(/^ | $/g,"");l.length&&n.push([T,new RegExp("^(?:"+l.replace(/[\s,]+/g,"|")+")\\b"),null]),t.push([B,/^\s+/,null," \r\n  "]);var o=/^.[^\s\w\.$@\'\"\`\/\\]*/;return n.push([A,/^@[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i,null],[P,/^(?:[@_]?[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z_$@0-9]*|\w+_t\b)/,null],[B,/^[a-z_$][a-z_$@0-9]*/i,null],[A,new RegExp("^(?:0x[a-f0-9]+|(?:\\d(?:_\\d+)*\\d*(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d\\+)(?:e[+\\-]?\\d+)?)[a-z]*","i"),null,"0123456789"],[B,/^\\[\s\S]?/,null],[R,o,null]),r(t,n)}function a(e,t,n){function s(e){switch(e.nodeType){case 1:if(i.test(e.className))break;if("br"===e.nodeName)r(e),e.parentNode&&e.parentNode.removeChild(e);else for(var t=e.firstChild;t;t=t.nextSibling)s(t);break;case 3:case 4:if(n){var o=e.nodeValue,h=o.match(a);if(h){var u=o.substring(0,h.index);e.nodeValue=u;var c=o.substring(h.index+h[0].length);if(c){var p=e.parentNode;p.insertBefore(l.createTextNode(c),e.nextSibling)}r(e),u||e.parentNode.removeChild(e)}}}}function r(e){function t(e,n){var s=n?e.cloneNode(!1):e,r=e.parentNode;if(r){var i=t(r,1),a=e.nextSibling;i.appendChild(s);for(var l=a;l;l=a)a=l.nextSibling,i.appendChild(l)}return s}for(;!e.nextSibling;)if(e=e.parentNode,!e)return;for(var n,s=t(e.nextSibling,0);(n=s.parentNode)&&1===n.nodeType;)s=n;h.push(s)}for(var i=/(?:^|\s)nocode(?:\s|$)/,a=/\r\n?|\n/,l=e.ownerDocument,o=l.createElement("li");e.firstChild;)o.appendChild(e.firstChild);for(var h=[o],u=0;u<h.length;++u)s(h[u]);t===(0|t)&&h[0].setAttribute("value",t);var c=l.createElement("ol");c.className="linenums";for(var p=Math.max(0,t-1|0)||0,u=0,g=h.length;g>u;++u)o=h[u],o.className="L"+(u+p)%10,o.firstChild||o.appendChild(l.createTextNode(" ")),c.appendChild(o);e.appendChild(c)}function l(e){var t=/\bMSIE\s(\d+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent);t=t&&+t[1]<=8;var n=/\n/g,s=e.sourceCode,r=s.length,i=0,a=e.spans,l=a.length,o=0,h=e.decorations,u=h.length,c=0;h[u]=r;var p,g;for(g=p=0;u>g;)h[g]!==h[g+2]?(h[p++]=h[g++],h[p++]=h[g++]):g+=2;for(u=p,g=p=0;u>g;){for(var d=h[g],f=h[g+1],m=g+2;u>=m+2&&h[m+1]===f;)m+=2;h[p++]=d,h[p++]=f,g=m}u=h.length=p;var b,x=e.sourceNode;x&&(b=x.style.display,x.style.display="none");try{for(;l>o;){var y,v=(a[o],a[o+2]||r),k=h[c+2]||r,m=Math.min(v,k),w=a[o+1];if(1!==w.nodeType&&(y=s.substring(i,m))){t&&(y=y.replace(n,"\r")),w.nodeValue=y;var S=w.ownerDocument,_=S.createElement("span");_.className=h[c+1];var C=w.parentNode;C.replaceChild(_,w),_.appendChild(w),v>i&&(a[o+1]=w=S.createTextNode(s.substring(m,v)),C.insertBefore(w,_.nextSibling))}i=m,i>=v&&(o+=2),i>=k&&(c+=2)}}finally{x&&(x.style.display=b)}}function o(e,t){for(var n=t.length;--n>=0;){var s=t[n];H.hasOwnProperty(s)?g.console&&console.warn("cannot override language handler %s",s):H[s]=e}}function h(e,t){return e&&H.hasOwnProperty(e)||(e=/^\s*</.test(t)?"default-markup":"default-code"),H[e]}function u(e){var n=e.langExtension;try{var s=t(e.sourceNode,e.pre),r=s.sourceCode;e.sourceCode=r,e.spans=s.spans,e.basePos=0,h(n,r)(e),l(e)}catch(i){g.console&&console.log(i&&i.stack?i.stack:i)}}function c(e,t,n){var s=document.createElement("pre");s.innerHTML=e,n&&a(s,n,!0);var r={langExtension:t,numberLines:n,sourceNode:s,pre:1};return u(r),s.innerHTML}function p(e){function t(e){return document.getElementsByTagName(e)}function n(){for(var t=g.PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION?c.now()+250:1/0;d<i.length&&c.now()<t;d++){var r=i[d],l=r.className;if(m.test(l)&&!b.test(l)){for(var o=!1,h=r.parentNode;h;h=h.parentNode){var k=h.tagName;if(v.test(k)&&h.className&&m.test(h.className)){o=!0;break}}if(!o){r.className+=" prettyprinted";var w,S=l.match(f);!S&&(w=s(r))&&y.test(w.tagName)&&(S=w.className.match(f)),S&&(S=S[1]);var _;if(x.test(r.tagName))_=1;else{var C=r.currentStyle,N=C?C.whiteSpace:document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle?document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(r,null).getPropertyValue("white-space"):0;_=N&&"pre"===N.substring(0,3)}var $=r.className.match(/\blinenums\b(?::(\d+))?/);$=$?$[1]&&$[1].length?+$[1]:!0:!1,$&&a(r,$,_),p={langExtension:S,sourceNode:r,numberLines:$,pre:_},u(p)}}}d<i.length?setTimeout(n,250):e&&e()}for(var r=[t("pre"),t("code"),t("xmp")],i=[],l=0;l<r.length;++l)for(var o=0,h=r[l].length;h>o;++o)i.push(r[l][o]);r=null;var c=Date;c.now||(c={now:function(){return+new Date}});var p,d=0,f=/\blang(?:uage)?-([\w.]+)(?!\S)/,m=/\bprettyprint\b/,b=/\bprettyprinted\b/,x=/pre|xmp/i,y=/^code$/i,v=/^(?:pre|code|xmp)$/i;n()}var g=window,d=["break,continue,do,else,for,if,return,while"],f=[d,"auto,case,char,const,default,double,enum,extern,float,goto,int,long,register,short,signed,sizeof,static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile"],m=[f,"catch,class,delete,false,import,new,operator,private,protected,public,this,throw,true,try,typeof"],b=[m,"alignof,align_union,asm,axiom,bool,concept,concept_map,const_cast,constexpr,decltype,dynamic_cast,explicit,export,friend,inline,late_check,mutable,namespace,nullptr,reinterpret_cast,static_assert,static_cast,template,typeid,typename,using,virtual,where"],x=[m,"abstract,boolean,byte,extends,final,finally,implements,import,instanceof,null,native,package,strictfp,super,synchronized,throws,transient"],y=[x,"as,base,by,checked,decimal,delegate,descending,dynamic,event,fixed,foreach,from,group,implicit,in,interface,internal,into,is,let,lock,object,out,override,orderby,params,partial,readonly,ref,sbyte,sealed,stackalloc,string,select,uint,ulong,unchecked,unsafe,ushort,var,virtual,where"],v="all,and,by,catch,class,else,extends,false,finally,for,if,in,is,isnt,loop,new,no,not,null,of,off,on,or,return,super,then,throw,true,try,unless,until,when,while,yes",k=[m,"debugger,eval,export,function,get,null,set,undefined,var,with,Infinity,NaN"],w="caller,delete,die,do,dump,elsif,eval,exit,foreach,for,goto,if,import,last,local,my,next,no,our,print,package,redo,require,sub,undef,unless,until,use,wantarray,while,BEGIN,END",S=[d,"and,as,assert,class,def,del,elif,except,exec,finally,from,global,import,in,is,lambda,nonlocal,not,or,pass,print,raise,try,with,yield,False,True,None"],_=[d,"alias,and,begin,case,class,def,defined,elsif,end,ensure,false,in,module,next,nil,not,or,redo,rescue,retry,self,super,then,true,undef,unless,until,when,yield,BEGIN,END"],C=[d,"case,done,elif,esac,eval,fi,function,in,local,set,then,until"],N=[b,y,k,w+S,_,C],$=/^(DIR|FILE|vector|(de|priority_)?queue|list|stack|(const_)?iterator|(multi)?(set|map)|bitset|u?(int|float)\d*)\b/,E="str",T="kwd",L="com",P="typ",A="lit",R="pun",B="pln",I="tag",O="dec",q="src",z="atn",M="atv",j="nocode",D="(?:^^\\.?|[+-]|[!=]=?=?|\\#|%=?|&&?=?|\\(|\\*=?|[+\\-]=|->|\\/=?|::?|<<?=?|>>?>?=?|,|;|\\?|@|\\[|~|{|\\^\\^?=?|\\|\\|?=?|break|case|continue|delete|do|else|finally|instanceof|return|throw|try|typeof)\\s*",U=/\S/,V=i({keywords:N,hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),H={};o(V,["default-code"]),o(r([],[[B,/^[^<?]+/],[O,/^<!\w[^>]*(?:>|$)/],[L,/^<\!--[\s\S]*?(?:-\->|$)/],["lang-",/^<\?([\s\S]+?)(?:\?>|$)/],["lang-",/^<%([\s\S]+?)(?:%>|$)/],[R,/^(?:<[%?]|[%?]>)/],["lang-",/^<xmp\b[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/xmp\b[^>]*>/i],["lang-js",/^<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/script\b[^>]*>)/i],["lang-css",/^<style\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)(<\/style\b[^>]*>)/i],["lang-in.tag",/^(<\/?[a-z][^<>]*>)/i]]),["default-markup","htm","html","mxml","xhtml","xml","xsl"]),o(r([[B,/^[\s]+/,null,"  \r\n"],[M,/^(?:\"[^\"]*\"?|\'[^\']*\'?)/,null,"\"'"]],[[I,/^^<\/?[a-z](?:[\w.:-]*\w)?|\/?>$/i],[z,/^(?!style[\s=]|on)[a-z](?:[\w:-]*\w)?/i],["lang-uq.val",/^=\s*([^>\'\"\s]*(?:[^>\'\"\s\/]|\/(?=\s)))/],[R,/^[=<>\/]+/],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/i],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*\'([^\']+)\'/i],["lang-js",/^on\w+\s*=\s*([^\"\'>\s]+)/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*\'([^\']+)\'/i],["lang-css",/^style\s*=\s*([^\"\'>\s]+)/i]]),["in.tag"]),o(r([],[[M,/^[\s\S]+/]]),["uq.val"]),o(i({keywords:b,hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,types:$}),["c","cc","cpp","cxx","cyc","m"]),o(i({keywords:"null,true,false"}),["json"]),o(i({keywords:y,hashComments:!0,cStyleComments:!0,verbatimStrings:!0,types:$}),["cs"]),o(i({keywords:x,cStyleComments:!0}),["java"]),o(i({keywords:C,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0}),["bsh","csh","sh"]),o(i({keywords:S,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,tripleQuotedStrings:!0}),["cv","py"]),o(i({keywords:w,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["perl","pl","pm"]),o(i({keywords:_,hashComments:!0,multiLineStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["rb"]),o(i({keywords:k,cStyleComments:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["js"]),o(i({keywords:v,hashComments:3,cStyleComments:!0,multilineStrings:!0,tripleQuotedStrings:!0,regexLiterals:!0}),["coffee"]),o(r([],[[E,/^[\s\S]+/]]),["regex"]);var F=g.PR={createSimpleLexer:r,registerLangHandler:o,sourceDecorator:i,PR_ATTRIB_NAME:z,PR_ATTRIB_VALUE:M,PR_COMMENT:L,PR_DECLARATION:O,PR_KEYWORD:T,PR_LITERAL:A,PR_NOCODE:j,PR_PLAIN:B,PR_PUNCTUATION:R,PR_SOURCE:q,PR_STRING:E,PR_TAG:I,PR_TYPE:P,prettyPrintOne:g.prettyPrintOne=c,prettyPrint:g.prettyPrint=p};"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("google-code-prettify",[],function(){return F})}(),function(e,t){t.body.style.display="none",t.head=t.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],"getElementsByClassName"in t||(t.getElementsByClassName=function(e){function n(e,t){for(var n=[],s=new RegExp("(^| )"+t+"( |$)"),r=e.getElementsByTagName("*"),i=0,a=r.length;a>i;i++)s.test(r[i].className)&&n.push(r[i]);return n}return n(t.body,e)});var n=t.getElementsByTagName("xmp")[0]||t.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0],s=t.getElementsByTagName("title")[0],r=t.getElementsByTagName("script"),i=t.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0],a=t.createElement("meta");a.name="viewport",a.content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0",t.head.firstChild?t.head.insertBefore(a,t.head.firstChild):t.head.appendChild(a);for(var l="",o=0;o<r.length;o++)r[o].src.match("strapdown")&&(l=r[o].src);var h=l.substr(0,l.lastIndexOf("/")),u=n.getAttribute("theme")||"bootstrap";u=u.toLowerCase();var c=t.createElement("link");c.href=h+"/themes/"+u+".min.css",c.rel="stylesheet",t.head.appendChild(c);var c=t.createElement("link");c.href=h+"/strapdown.css",c.rel="stylesheet",t.head.appendChild(c);var c=t.createElement("link");c.href=h+"/themes/bootstrap-responsive.min.css",c.rel="stylesheet",t.head.appendChild(c);var p=n.textContent||n.innerText,g=t.createElement("div");g.className="container",g.id="content",t.body.replaceChild(g,n);var g=t.createElement("div");if(g.className="navbar navbar-fixed-top",!i&&s){g.innerHTML='<div class="navbar-inner"> <div class="container"> <div id="headline" class="brand"> </div> </div> </div>',t.body.insertBefore(g,t.body.firstChild);var d=s.innerHTML,f=t.getElementById("headline");f&&(f.innerHTML=d)}var m=marked(p);t.getElementById("content").innerHTML=m;for(var b=t.getElementsByTagName("code"),o=0,x=b.length;x>o;o++){var y=b[o],v=y.className;y.className="prettyprint lang-"+v}prettyPrint();for(var k=t.getElementsByTagName("table"),o=0,x=k.length;x>o;o++){var w=k[o];w.className="table table-striped table-bordered"}t.body.style.display=""}(window,document);
```

```html
Este é o demo em HTML:
<xmp>Olá, _**está** tudo_ bem?</xmp>
```

Só que o SOpt não faz isso do lado do cliente, e sim nos servidores da aplicação.

A grande vantagem de fazer isto do lado do servidor é que você processa os dados apenas uma vez, e já entrega pronto para o usuário final sem dependências externas (e sem precisar mandar o JS que faz a conversão junto).

Citei o [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/) simplesmente por ter sido uma das primeiras coisas que apareceu fazendo uma pesquisa básica no DuckDuckGo, tem uma diversidade absurda de outras aplicações similares. Qualquer uma que você pegue como referência, tem os conceitos básicos no código-fonte como ponto de partida.

Comment: Bacco, com sua explicação pude ter uma noção do que se trata os _markdowns_ , não tinha conhecimento dessa nomenclatura.

Comment: @SamirBraga Só pra constar, a nomenclatura é _markup_ (nome genérico) mesmo. _Markdown_ é uma nomenclatura para uma formatação bem específica, tem mil outras. Postei uma de _markdown_ como exemplo por ser praticamente a mesma que usamos aqui. Tem outras mais complicadas e mais simples.

Comment: @Bacco Veja a [resposta abaixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212596/132) inspirada na sua.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não sei se dá pra chamar de "inspirada". O código é o mesmo que eu pus aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98380/70, não? Inclusive, eu já havia atualizado mais cedo a minha postagem com base nisso. O autor da postagem simplesmente trocou o link da CDN

Answer (score 0):

**Atualização:**
Segundo esse link https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ o CDN citado pelo @Bacco sairá de operação e deverá ser substituído por `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js` como no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<h3>Original:</h3>
sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2
<h3>Resultado:</h3>
`sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/135908)

Comment: @Dvdsamm Esse caso está bem em cima da linha do que divide o que deveria ser um comentário na resposta do Bacco e o do que é uma outra resposta diferente baseada na resposta anterior. Assim sendo, achei mais prudente dar ao autor da resposta o benefício da dúvida e votar em "Parece OK", mas fiquei em dúvida.