# Como percorrer string e substituir ** por <b></b>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ultimamente tenho usado alguns sistemas que tem a seguinte função, ao escrever um texto entre `**` ele transforma esse texto em negrito por exemplo:

Julio *henrique* dos Santos

resultado esperado será:

Julio **henrique** dos Santos

Pensei em criar algo parecido utilizando javascript e html, porem encontrei muitas dificuldades:

Div resultado:

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

**Código Javascript e jQuery:**

```
var str = "Visit jsduflsd fjkdsufdsjlkfds djfuldsifjdlsk *jflusdlkfjdsds* jfdisufkljds!";
var res = str.replace("*", "<b>");
$("#text").html(res);
```

Infelizmente não consegui sair dai. Ele troca o primeiro `*` por um `<b>`, mas não o fecha e tem que ser algo flexível para fazer sempre que ocorrer isso na *string*. Existe alguma forma? Pensei em REGEX, mas não sei se seria cabível.

Comment: Resposta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98376/5878

Comment: Seria apenas 1 negrito ou poderia ocorrer mais de 1?

Comment: Opa Sam! seria mais vezes, esta no fim da pergunta :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usando regex:

```js
var str = "*Visit* jsduflsd \\*fjkdsufdsjlkfds\\* djfuldsifjdlsk *jflusdlkfjdsds* jfdisufkljds!";
var res = (" "+str).replace(/([^\\])\*([^\*]*)([^\\])\*/g, "$1<b>$2$3</b>");
res = res.trim();
res = res.replace(/\\\*/g, "*");
document.write(res)
```

- `(` Inicia a captura de caracteres
- `[^\\]` Qualquer caracter que seja diferente de `\`
- `)` Fecha a captura de caracteres
- `\*` Inicia com`*` a `\` para escapar
- `(` Inicia a captura de caracteres
- `[^\*]*` todos os caracteres diferentes de `*` repetidos 0 ou muitas vezes
- `)` Fecha a captura de caracteres
- `(` Inicia a captura de caracteres
- `[^\\]` Qualquer caracter que seja diferente de `\`
- `)` Fecha a captura de caracteres
- `\*` Termina com`*` a `\` para escapar
- `$1`, `$2` e `$3` Serve para "colar" o que foi capturado

Pegar todos os `*` não precedidos de `\` serve para poder escapa-los, porém isso obriga que haja um caracter antes do `*`, se a string começar com o markdown de negrito, irá falhar, pois não existe um caracter anterior. Para resolver isso é adcionado um  antes (`(" "+str)`) e é tirado depois com `trim`. Também é necessário "repor" esse caracter anterior, por isso o `$1` e `$2` Depois de fazer a troca para as tags HTML então é trocado os markdowns escapados (`\*` para `*`)

Exemplo de uso mais dinâmico:

```js
String.prototype.markdown = function(caracter, tag) {
  return (" "+this).replace(new RegExp(`([^\\\\])\\${caracter.split('').join('\\')}([^\\${caracter.split('').join('\\')}]*)([^\\\\])\\${caracter.split('').join('\\')}`, 'g'), `$1<${tag}>$2$3</${tag}>`).trim().split(`\\${caracter}`).join(caracter);
}

document.querySelector('textarea').oninput = function() {
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = this.value.markdown('*', 'b').markdown('--', 'strike');
}
```

```html
<textarea cols='75'>--riscado-- \--riscado\-- *negrito* \*negrito\*</textarea>

<p>
```

<sup>De um espaço no `textarea` para carregar com o exemplo</sup>

Comment: Minha única sugestão seria usar a flag `g` na regex, para substituir todas as ocorrência e não apenas a primeira. `/\*([^\*]*)\*/g`

Comment: @fernandosavio muito bem lembrado, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta com um exemplo mais completo

Answer (score 3):

Regex certamente é a forma mais prática e direta de resolver o problema como o @GuilheremCostamilam já mostrou. O `replace` recebendo uma string como substituição funciona apenas para uma substituição e não todas, por isso não daria para resolver sem regex.

[O MDN reforça este ponto de forma evidente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced

No entanto também seria possível de resolver manualmente, ainda que bem mais trabalhoso. Para tal, teria que ter uma variável booleana para saber se vai adicionar o inicio da tag ou fim da tag, e cada vez que achar um `*` faz a troca pelo inicio/fecho consoante o booleano. Após cada troca tem de alternar o booleano.

Exemplo:

```js
var str = "Visit *jsduflsd* fjkdsufdsjlkfds djfuldsifjdlsk *jflusdlkfjdsds* jfdisufkljds!";

let inicio = true, res = "";
for (let letra of str){
  if (letra === '*'){
    res += inicio ? "<b>": "</b>";
    inicio = !inicio;
  }
  else res += letra;
}

document.write(res);
```

Se houver a possibilidade do haver um * perdido sem o respetivo par e que não queiramos que forma-te a negrito, então já é necessário algumas preocupações adicionais, que irão complicar e aumentar um pouco o código.

Exemplo:

```js
var str = "Visit *jsduflsd* fjkdsufdsjlkfds djfuldsifjdlsk *jflusdlkfjdsds jfdisufkljds!";

let emBold = false, res = "", blocoBold ="";
for (let letra of str){
  if (letra === '*'){
    emBold = !emBold;
    if (emBold)
      blocoBold = "";
    else //só no fecho é que adiciona o bloco todo
      res += "<b>" + blocoBold + "</b>";
  }
  else {
    if (emBold)
      blocoBold += letra;
    else 
      res += letra;
  }
}

res += blocoBold;//adiciona o que ficou por fechar sem as tags
document.write(res);
```

Comment: O único problema é se a pessoa "abriu o negrito" e não fechou: `example *negrito não fechado` todo o resto da página pode ficar em negrito e quebrar

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Bem visto, que não tinha pensado nesse caso particular. Editei a resposta para contemplar também essa situação na mesma sem regex.