# Regex - Pegar formatação sem strings em volta

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma regex pra pegar formatação do slack.

Ex.:
`*a*` => Pega pra deixar negrito

Uma regex inicial que fiz foi:

```
/\*(.*?)\*/g
```

**O problema:**

- Não pode ter nada em volta da string(Nenhum caractere grudado antes ou depois)
- Pode ser o começo da linha

---

Situações que deviam funcionar:

```
*a*
a *a* a
```

Situações que **NÃO** deviam funcionar:

```
b*a*
*a*b
*a**
**a*
```

Comment: Outra possível: [Criar marcação com símbolos pré-definidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98369/5878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Buscando os asteriscos: `\*([^\*]+?)\*(?!\*)`

**2)** Adicionando as tags para negrito: `<strong>$2</strong>`

Agora é só aplicar no seu projeto:

```js
let str = 'Lorem *ipsum dolor* sit amet, *consectetur** adipisicing elit. Optio repellat ipsa quibusdam ab doloremque accusamus nobis minima maiores voluptas, incidunt rerum alias, aliquam ut minus consequatur odio voluptatibus voluptates exercitationem.';

str = str.replace(/\*([^\*]+?)\*(?!\*)/i, '<strong>$1</strong>');

console.log(str);
```

**@edit** Agora não vai *encontrar* caso tenha dois asteriscos juntos, sem nada dentro.

**@edit2** Agora não vai *encontrar* caso tenha dois asteriscos juntos ao final da expressão buscada, como lembrou o [@sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam) (`*expressão**`). E aprimorei conforme sugestão do [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/).

> Exemplo funcionando: [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ahHCFB/1)

Comment: Se colocar um asterisco junto irá funcionar: `*ipsum dolor**`... Mas na pergunta diz que essa situação não deveria funcionar: `*a**`.

Comment: É melhor colocar `[^*]+` (qq coisa que não seja asterisco) para evitar *backtracking* excessivo qdo não tiver o segundo `*`. Veja que com `.+` [a regex executa mais de 1000 passos](https://regex101.com/r/FGCA6Q/1/debugger) até perceber que não tem o segundo `*`, enquanto usando `[^*]+` ela leva [menos da metade](https://regex101.com/r/ulnxNg/1/debugger) - e isso [aumenta absurdamente conforme o tamanho do texto](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @Sam corrigido! hkotsubo Gostei da ideia. Código atualizado!

Comment: Poxa, legal. E tem uma forma de evitar que quando tem um caractere ao lado, não funcione? Tipo: a[asterisco]a[asterisco] não funcionar por causa do caractere grudado nele. Estou precisando fazer isso pq no slack ele não funciona se tiver algo antes ou depois.

Comment: Tem como sim! Pesquise sobre *regex negative/positive lookahead/lookbehind*. Nesse exemplo aí na resposta utilizei o *negative lookahead*: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda!